# Any Idea how to migrate from PostgresSQL 8.4 to PostgresSQL 9.1.1 in opensuse12.1

Tags: postgresql, linux, upgrade

I had a crashed opensuse 11.3 that's why I installed opensuse 12.1.. 
after I installed (via yast) and edited /etc/passwd

I do this:

```
 rcpostgresql start
```

and this shows on the /var/log/messeges

```
~ # less  /var/log/messages  | grep postgres
Dec 27 10:43:08 t1libora1 shadow[2393]: new group added - group=postgres, gid=26, by=0
Dec 27 10:43:08 t1libora1 shadow[2393]: running GROUPADD_CMD command - script=/usr/sbin/groupadd.local, account=postgres, uid=26, gid=0, home=, by=0
Dec 27 10:43:08 t1libora1 useradd[2396]: new account added - account=postgres, uid=26, gid=26, home=/var/lib/pgsql, shell=/bin/bash, by=0
Dec 27 10:43:08 t1libora1 useradd[2396]: running USERADD_CMD command - script=/usr/sbin/useradd.local, account=postgres, uid=26, gid=26, home=/var/lib/pgsql, by=0
Dec 27 11:08:45 t1libora1 su: (to postgres) root on none
Dec 27 11:08:45 t1libora1 postgresql[2998]: Starting PostgreSQL2011-12-27 13:08:45 GMT   FATAL:  los archivos de base de datos son incompatibles con el servidor
**Dec 27 11:08:45 t1libora1 postgresql[2998]: 2011-12-27 13:08:45 GMT   DETALLE:  El directorio de datos fue inicializado por PostgreSQL versión 8.4, que no es compatible con esta versión 9.1.1.**
Dec 27 11:08:50 t1libora1 postgresql[2998]: pg_ctl: no se pudo iniciar el servidor.
Dec 27 11:08:50 t1libora1 postgresql[2998]: Examine el registro del servidor.
Dec 27 11:08:50 t1libora1 postgresql[2998]: ..failed
Dec 27 11:08:50 t1libora1 systemd[1]: postgresql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 27 11:08:50 t1libora1 systemd[1]: Unit postgresql.service entered failed state.
```

how can I migrate?

Comment: have you tried [pg_upgrade](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/pgupgrade.html)?

Comment: yeah... but but had a bug... tomorrow I will edit this and add the bug's info.

Comment: There were several fixes to `pg_upgrade` in 9.1.2 so you might consider using that instead of 9.1.1 (using 9.1.2 is recommended anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a perfect world, you'd have a backup of your databases created with **pg_dump**. If you did, you could restore those database backups to your 9.1 version.  Otherwise, you could reinstall 8.4 somewhere else, copy in your original database files and make a backup of all your databases and users.  Then restore that backup to your 9.1

**Install your old version of PostgreSQL**

1.Install an instance of PostgreSQL 8.4, **same version** as you had on OpenSUSE 11.3.  This doesn't have to be on the same machine.  If it does, you could compile
a version from a .tar.gz. example: http://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v8.4.8/postgresql-8.4.8.tar.gz

Decompress, configure, make and install to some other directory

2.Make sure your 9.1 isn't listening otherwise 8.4 will not be able to use the 5432 port.

3.start up postgres. **somedirectory/data** is where you have your 8.4 data files.

```
su - postgres

/postgresql84_directory/bin/pg_ctl start -D /somedirectory/data -l serverlog
```

4.Backup your databases to a text file

```
/postgresql84_directory/bin/pg_dumpall > all.dbs_8.4.sql
```

5.Stop postgresql 8.4

/`postgresql84_directory/bin/pg_ctl -D /somedirectory/data -l logfile stop`

**Restore your 8.4 dump file to 9.1**

1.If your 9.1 version isn't working anymore, you will probably want to reinitalize your data directory.

```
/postgresql91_directory/bin/initdb -D /postgresql91_directory/data/
```

2.Startup Postgresql9.1 again

3.Now restore the 8.4 dump file to your 9.1 instance

```
/postgresql91_directory/bin/psql -f all.dbs_8.4.sql
```